# Remove Trailing Slash in ASP.NET MVC 4 Route to Application Root

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

In my ASP.NET MVC 4 application's `RouteConfig` file, I have registered the following default route:

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "home", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Now, in my Razor views, I want to generate a URL to my application's root like that:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("index", "home")">Home</a>
```

The generated URL includes a trailing slash; clicking the link thus opens the page *localhost/IISApplicationName*/. However, I want the URL not to contain the trailing slash so that the URL is *localhost/IISApplicationName*. Generating routes for other actions, such as */Account/Login*, does not create URLs with trailing slashes — it's just about the route linking to my application's root.

**Is there any way to prevent ASP.NET MVC routing from appending the trailing slash to the above route?**

(I know that I can redirect from the URL including the slash to the one without it, but I'd rather have routing generate the correct route URL in the first place.)

Comment: I cannot duplicate your problem I use `Default route` and it goes to url without `/`

Comment: just for information, what's the problem with trailing slash?

Comment: @alexanderb 1) Both links end up showing the same page despite having slightly different URLs. Not good ... 2) It's ugly ;-).

Comment: I think that one could be useful: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/generating-traditional-urls-with-asp-net-mvc3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to prevent ASP.NET MVC routing from appending the
>   trailing slash to the above route?

**You should pass a trailing slash when the relative path is empty.** If you somehow generate links with href `localhost/IISApplicationName` still the browser appends a "/" at the end (you can easily verify this in firebug, just type http://stackoverflow.com in the browser address bar and check the requests tab you can see the trailing "/").

This is because as per the HTTP/1.1,

> the absolute path cannot be emtpy; if none is present in the original
>   URI, it mut be given as "/" (the server root).

http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html#ixzz0kGcaRbqU (section 5.1.2)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend URL Rwrite Outbounds rules.

[Creating Outbound Rules for URL Rewrite Module : URL Rewrite Module 2 : URL Rewrite Module : The Official Microsoft IIS Site](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/657/creating-outbound-rules-for-url-rewrite-module/)

Sample config:

```
    <rewrite>
        <outboundRules>
            <rule name="RewriteSlash">
                <match filterByTags="A" pattern="^/IISApplicationName/$" />
                <action type="Rewrite" value="/IISApplicationName" />
            </rule>
        </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
```