# What is adding the trailing slash in my MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewriting, iis-express

- .NET 4.51, MVC 5, VS 2013, IIS Express

I am trying to get my development environment set up so that when I run the project it opens up as **https://localhost:44300**, however for some reason the page is opening with the trailing slash namely **https://localhost:44300/**

After reading [Remove Trailing Slash in ASP.NET MVC 4 Route to Application Root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325425/remove-trailing-slash-in-asp-net-mvc-4-route-to-application-root) I am unable to use any of the suggestions in there in terms of outbound rewrites to make the trailing slash go away. My motivation for not having the trailing slash is for SEO purposes. Our SEO people do not want a trailing slash under any circumstances.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection aRoutes)
{
    aRoutes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    aRoutes.AppendTrailingSlash = false;
    aRoutes.LowercaseUrls = true;

    aRoutes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new
                                                              {
                                                                  controller = "Home",
                                                                  action = "Index",
                                                                  id = UrlParameter.Optional
                                                              }
        );
}
```

and my project settings are:

[image]
[image]

I have also tried the following rewrite rule but it has made no difference:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  <handlers>
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
    <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  </handlers>

  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <!--To always remove trailing slash from the URL-->
      <rule name="Remove trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)/$" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

So how do I get the trailing slash to not be there when I open up the default route? All other routes e.g /MyRoute/ end up as expected namely /MyRoute.

Comment: Have you verified that it's not just the browser popping it in there? For instance, in Chrome although my proj url has a trailing slash as per project properties, Chrome never shows it. But if you look at the network GET request in dev tools, the actual url it's hitting has one. So maybe it's just your browsers address bar. IE on the other hand always shows it even when i remove it.

Comment: But if you F12 in IE and look at the detail for the request headers, you can see it's not using the trailing slash for the GET.

Comment: @rism HttpContext.Request.Url is showing the trailing slash and so is FireBug when I look at the request.

Comment: `Request.Url` is Uri. If you `var url = new Uri("http://www.google.com")`, and break point it you're going to get `http://www.google.com/`. It's the response headers that matter. Btw http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.fr/2010/04/to-slash-or-not-to-slash.html